# A file named (something) already exist

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2022

Hi using VS 2022 fresh install, new project i keep getting a file named XXX already exist, ive tried restaarting vs, checking solution explorer for hidden files, unloiading and reloading the project and even cleaed my temp folder

[before adding new item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gi5rx.png)

[After selecting item to add is same with any item i select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8yOG.png)

Comment: If you create a new project, does the problem still happen?

Comment: yes is happens with everynew project i crate

Comment: Have you tried repairing VS by using the Visual Studio Installer? (Under the "More" dropdown.)

Comment: just tried that still the same

Comment: Do you have a third-party anti-virus program installed?

Comment: no only windows

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report